# (Cygwin - make) file not recognized: File format not recognized collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: windows, terminal, makefile, cygwin

I'm using Cygwin (in windows 7) to emulate Linux terminal, however, when I execute "make" to one of the files, I get the following error, (please note that this worked in Linux terminal)

```
cd ./agents/randomAgentJava/ && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/f/Linux Files/Helicopter_Control/rl-competition/agents/randomAgentJava'
javac -source 5 -d bin -cp ../../system/libraries/RLVizLib.jar src/RandomAgent/RandomAgent.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.5
1 warning
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/f/Linux Files/Helicopter_Control/rl-competition/agents/randomAgentJava'
cd ./agents/randomAgentCPP/ && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/f/Linux Files/Helicopter_Control/rl-competition/agents/randomAgentCPP'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/f/Linux Files/Helicopter_Control/rl-competition/agents/randomAgentCPP'
cd ./agents/mountainCarAgentCPP/ && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/f/Linux Files/Helicopter_Control/rl-competition/agents/mountainCarAgentCPP'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/f/Linux Files/Helicopter_Control/rl-competition/agents/mountainCarAgentCPP'
cd ./agents/realTimeStrategyAgentJava/ && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/f/Linux Files/Helicopter_Control/rl-competition/agents/realTimeStrategyAgentJava'
javac src/**/*.java -d bin -cp ../../system/libraries/RLVizLib.jar
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/f/Linux Files/Helicopter_Control/rl-competition/agents/realTimeStrategyAgentJava'
cd ./agents/helicopterAgentCPP/ && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/f/Linux Files/Helicopter_Control/rl-competition/agents/helicopterAgentCPP'
g++ -c -I../../system/RL-Glue/RL-Glue -I../../system/RL-Glue/Utils -I./src src/weak_baseline_controller.cpp -o bin/weak_baseline_controller.o
g++ -o ./bin/RL_agent bin/weak_baseline_controller.o bin/Glue_utilities.o bin/RL_client_agent.o bin/RL_network.o -lm
bin/Glue_utilities.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:25: recipe for target `bin/RL_agent' failed
make[1]: *** [bin/RL_agent] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/f/Linux Files/Helicopter_Control/rl-competition/agents/helicopterAgentCPP'
Makefile:13: recipe for target `all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The file `bin/Glue_utilities.o` is not a Cygwin object file.  It must be built for some other target.  If you run `file bin/Glue_utilities.o` you'll find out more.

Comment: Thanks, @MadScientist, so there is no solution? Is there a way to execute "make " in Windows for these type of files?

Comment: You haven't told us what type of file you have, so we can't really say.  But basically, since the linker is complaining, no: if the object file is compiled for a different target then you can't link it with object files for this target.  If you're trying to cross-compile for a different target you need a cross-linker.